# Вылетает ошибка при открытии URL подключения

Tags: java, url, httpclient

Есть код:

```
String site = "http://somesite...";
URL url = new URL(site);
HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlCon.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlCon.connect();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
String line=null;

while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
      buf.append(line + "\n");
}
```

На строке "urlCon.openConnection" программа переходит к блоку try-catch методы OnClick класса AppCompatViewInflater:

```
public void onClick(@ NonNull View v) {
     if (mResolvedMethod == null) {
         resolveMethod(mHostView.getContext(), mMethodName);
     }
     try {
         mResolvedMethod.invoke(mResolvedContext, v);
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                 "Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", e);
     } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
     }
}
```

И дальше выполняется строка

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
```

И это приводит к перезапуску программы.
Как можно исправить?

Comment: Выведите getCause() у объекта `e` типа `InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Если у вас андроид, то надо в другой поток запрос в сеть вынести

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, что именно из всего кода нужно вынести? С url.Con и до конца? Или вообще всё?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, файл с классом AppCompatViewInflater нельзя изменить, да и ошибку нигде не, кроме как в этом классе.

Comment: @Vya4eslav5213, сложно сказать. Вы привели куски кода, из которых лишь по косвенным признакам можно понять, что у вы под андроид пишите. При этом используете какие-то странные классы. На андроиде запросы в сеть принято делать сторонними либами. Например через OkHttp - оно даже позволит в фоне сделать запрос без лишних движений.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прошу прощения. Спасибо за совет)